# upload image via ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to upload an image via ajax call to php file and store in mysql. Following is the ajax call coding:

```
$('#save_user').click(function () {

    if (validateForm()) {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/user_add.php",
            data: {
                first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
                last_name: $("#last_name").val(),
                middle_name: $("#middle_name").val(),
                title: $("#title").val(),
                add1: $("#add1").val(),
                add2: $("#add2").val(),
                add3: $("#add3").val(),
                city_name: $("#city_name").val(),
                gender: $("#gender").val(),
                country_name: $("#country_code").val(),
                country_code: $("#country_code").val(),
                identity: $("#identity").val(),
                mobile: $("#mobile").val(),
                phone: $("#phone").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                new_username: $("#new_username").val(),
                dob: $("#dob").val(),
                image: $("#profile-img").val(),
                edit_user_id: $("#role_id").val(),
                register_user_role_id: $("#register_user_role_id").val()

            },
            dataType: "html"
        }).done(function (msg) {
            $('#success_useradd').html(msg);
            //alert generated from the php file after successful or error
            location.reload();
            //document reloaded

        });
    } else {
        //Any js to run if the validations fail
    }

});
```

The php file is as below:

But I cannot get the file saved in DB. I need to submit the information with an ajax call, as all my DB CRUD operations are done using ajax calls.. 
PHP file is as below:I am inserting the information to mysql table called users with the column name image.

```
    <?php

session_start();
include 'db_connect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) :

    $userrole = $_SESSION['role'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
else :
    $userrole = '0';
    header("location:login.php");
endif;
$image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$imgContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

function randomPassword() {
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array(); //declare $pass as an array
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}

$pass = randomPassword(); //generate random password and assign to the password variable. 
$new_username = $_POST['new_username'];
$pass_insert = sha1($pass);
$title = $_POST['title'];
$fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$mname = $_POST['middle_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$add1 = $_POST['add1'];
$add2 = $_POST['add2'];
$add3 = $_POST['add3'];
$identity = $_POST['identity'];
$city = $_POST['city_name'];
$country = $_POST['country_name'];
$country_code = $_POST['country_code'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$password_status = '0';
$user_status = 'P';
$role_id = $_POST['register_user_role_id'];
$create_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$update_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//User Insert Query
$newsql_add = "INSERT INTO `users` 
            (`id`, 
             `role_id`, 
             `username`, 
             `password`, 
             `title`, 
             `first_name`, 
             `middle_name`, 
             `last_name`, 
             `mobile`, 
             `phone`, 
             `email`, 
             `add1`, 
             `add2`, 
             `add3`, 
             `identity`, 
             `city`, 
             `country`, 
             `country_code`,
             `dob`, 
             `password_status`, 
             `user_status`, 
             `create_date`, 
             `last_updated_date`, 
             `passwordgen`,`image`) 
VALUES      ('', 
             '$role_id', 
             '$new_username', 
             '$pass_insert', 
             '$title', 
             '$fname', 
             '$mname', 
             '$lname', 
             '$mobile', 
             '$phone', 
             '$email', 
             '$add1', 
             '$add2', 
             '$add3', 
             '$identity', 
             '$city', 
             '$country', 
             '$country_code', 
             '$dob', 
             '$password_status', 
             '$user_status', 
             '$create_date', 
             '$update_date', 
             '$pass','$imgContent') ";
if ($new_user_add_query = mysqli_query($conn, $newsql_add)):

    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('User Added successfully')";
    echo "</script>";

else:
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert('User adding error')";
    echo "</script>";
endif;
```

Comment: Where is PHP code...? And Provide Form HTML also

Comment: Show me your `user_add.php` file code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: use form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and pass data in ajax request with `var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);` on form `submit` event

Comment: Please check, i have updated with the php file #hax0r